# recieving header(location:) as a callback from a php script in jquery .ajax

Tags: php, jquery

With this jquery :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tosql.php",
    data: {
        content: content
    },
    success: function() {


    }
});
```

I was wondering if I could receive a header(location: ) from the php, to redirect to another page with specific values stored in the url. Here is the url: `header(location: 'morefive.php?document='.urlencode($id))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tosql.php` returns `id` you could do this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tosql.php",
    data: {
        content: content
    },
    success: function(data){
    window.location = 'morefive.php?id=' + data;
    }
});
```

**Update :**

On tosql.php :

```
$_POST['content'];
// do something with content
echo $id; //say $id = 123
```

You would be directed to `morefive.php?id=123` on success.

Comment: can i get a specific variable back: specifically $id. i have many other variables but only want to return $id